# error: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend, swagger

Hola que tal? Estoy aprendiendo microservicios con Spring haciendo un curso, el caso es que, voy al inicio del proyecto y del curso, pero tengo el siguiente problema:

[image: Error generado en IntelliJ Idea de jetbrains]

esto me pasa con el IDE IntelliJ Idea de Jetbrains al ejecutar, no he probado en Eclipse o netbeans, tengo entendido que el problema está en Swagger en alguna cosa de configuración o método....

adjunto el customerApplication.java que es el main file de la app...
NOTA: las "DD" al costado de el método main fueron retiradas, así que no es problema de código mal escrito, según el IDE...

Por favor, pido su ayuda, de antemano, Gracias.

[image: Archivo principal de la app....]

Comment: El código es texto... ponlo como tal. Leer texto de las imágenes recortadas es un suplicio!

Comment: además de que así no sale la excepción completa y no te podemos ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te faltan un par de cosas:

En primer lugar, configurar Swagger con una clase de configuración, ej.:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
 public Docket api() {
     return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
             .select()
             .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
             .paths(PathSelectors.any())
             .build();
 }

}
```

Por otro lado, en las propiedades del proyecto puedes añadir configuraciones para swagger también
`swagger-ui: show: true`

Espero que te sirva, un saludo